# Font size of entries for LoF and LoT in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

I have a problem with the font size of the entries for List of figures and List of tables on the Contents index. If I change the fonts for the titles of LoF and LoT, the same changes are applied in their entries on Contents. How can I set the font size of the entries of LoF and LoT manually so as they look the same as the entries of the chapters?

I've used

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\fontsize{40}{0}{\selectfont{Contents}}}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}

\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\normalsize\bfseries}


\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\fontsize{40}{0}{\selectfont{List of figures}}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\fontsize{40}{0}{\selectfont{List of tables}}}
```

Comment: the `\xxxname` commands should only ever expand to text never font settings, but also `\fontsize{40}{0}{\selectfont{List of tables}}` is wrong, the `\selectfont` should not be inside a group, this leaves `\fontsize{40}{0}` in effect after this text and it will apply at the next `\selectfont` forcing a baselineskip of 0pt???

Answer (score 1):

It would have been helpful to provide an MWE. Instead I had to waste time creating one to try and answer your, rather unclear, question. Here is a brief one (less any typos) that you should consider as I think that it might be helpful to you.

```
% tocloftprob.tex  
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\begin{comment} % ignore your code
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\fontsize{40}{0}{\selectfont{Contents}}}
\renewcommand\cftsecfont{\LARGE\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsecpagefont{\LARGE\bfseries}

\renewcommand\cftsubsecfont{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftsubsecpagefont{\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cftloftitlefont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\fontsize{40}{0}{\selectfont{List of figures}}}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\fontsize{40}{0}{\selectfont{List of tables}}}
\end{comment} % end of your code

\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\itshape} % Change the font (and  position) of the titles
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large\itshape} % and for the LoF and Lot
\renewcommand{\cftlottitlefont}{\hfill\Large\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cftfigfont}{\bfseries} % change the font for figure entries
\renewcommand{\cftfigpagefont}{\bfseries} % change the font for figure caption pages

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{One}
\section{One}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{A Figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{A Table}
\end{table}

\chapter{Two}
\section{Two}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\caption{Another Figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Another Table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I suggest you read the `tocloft` documentation for further information (`> texdoc tocloft`).

GOM